# knockout foreach is not working for objects in Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have an array that has a list of objects and I am trying to loop through it but it seems to not working.

```html
<!-- ko foreach: applicationsAndProducts -->
                    <p>Apps and Products</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li data-bind="text: applicationsAndProducts.Product"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
```

applicationsAndProducts has 3 values as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should only be using `Product` instead of `applicationsAndProducts.Product`. Check the documentation for [foreach binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

```html
<!-- ko foreach: applicationsAndProducts -->
    <p>Apps and Products</p>
    <ul>
        <li data-bind="text: Product">
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```